# Partition of $\sigma$-field into atoms

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I was reading [this](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/greenbj/papers/conditional-expect.pdf) awesome article and I came across the following:

"I find it easiest to visualise the construction in the case that $X$ is a
finite set and $\mu$ is the counting measure, normalised so that $\mu(X) = 1$. In this case the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}'$ define partitions of $X$ into basic cells which we may call atoms."

I thought about this atom property and it doesn't seem to me that obvious whether such partitioning always exists or not, cause the smallest element containing $x$ might not belong to $\mathcal{F}$. Can somebody explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I was a bit busy. I totally forgot about the finite assumption. What do you think about the infinite case? Are there necessary and sufficient conditions?

Comment: In the infinite case, it may happen that $\mathcal{F}$ has no atom at all. 
However, in the general case (finite or infinite), we can prove: for each $x\in X$ there is a $\mathcal{F}$-atom $A_x$ such 
that $x\in A_x$ **if and only if** $\{A_x : x\in X, A_x \textrm{ is a  $\mathcal{F}$-atom and } x \in A_x\}$ is a 
partition of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $X$ is a finite set. So given $x\in X$, the set $B_x= \{ S \in \mathcal{F} : x\in S\}$  is finite. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a  $\sigma$-algebra, we have $X\in B_x$ ($B_x$ is not empty) and
$$A_x=\bigcap_{S\in B_x} S \in \mathcal{F}$$
Clearly $x\in A_x$, and $A_x$ is the smallest element in $\mathcal{F}$ containing $\{x\}$.

Note that if $y\in X$ and $y\neq x$, then $A_x\cap A_y=\emptyset$ or $A_x=A_y$.

(In fact, suppose  $A_x\cap A_y\neq \emptyset$ and $A_x\neq A_y$. Since $A_x\neq A_y$, either $A_x\setminus A_y\neq \emptyset$ or $A_y\setminus A_x\neq \emptyset$. Suppose without loss of generality that $A_x\setminus A_y\neq \emptyset$. 
Then $A_x\setminus A_y$ and $A_x\cap A_y$ are in $\mathcal{F}$ and are **proper** subsets of $A_x$. Moreover, $x\in A_x\setminus A_y$ or $x\in A_x\cap A_y$, which contradicts the fact that $A_x$ is the smallest element in $\mathcal{F}$ containing $\{x\}$).

It is easy to see that $\{A_x : x\in X \}$ is a partition of $X$.